# Unable to load images with Mojolicious web server

Tags: perl, mojolicious

It would seem that I'm not able to display images with Mojolicious in the web browser. My source code of my Perl script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  $c->render(text => "Hello World! This is an image: <img src=\"logo.png\"> ");
};

app->start;
```

When I load: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
the 'Hello World' text is displayed but the logo.png is not displayed - logo.png appears as a broken image as the web browser reports it is missing. The logo.png file is inside the same directory I'm running the above script from.

What must I do to get images and other external static files like javascript files, css, etc. to load inside the web page.

Comment: Try to put all static files into `public/` subfolder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Mojolicious serves static from the `public` subdirectory of your application. Try putting the image file in there. You can change the static file directory using `$app->static`.

Comment: perhaps `app->static`?

Comment: Not according to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious#static) I was reading. But I admit to knowing little about Mojolicious.

Comment: Ok, `Mojolicious::Lite` which OP uses differs in few minor details, https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Lite#app

Comment: There is no real difference between the two. `$app` is by convention of the documentation the application instance. In a Lite app, the `app` dsl keyword (read: function) simply returns that same instance.